# Not all lines are loaded into the database from Excel file

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, excel-2013

When I tried to upload data from Excel file to db only some rows uploaded. But when I Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C all data from this file and paste copied data to newly created file then try to upload this new file all rows upload fine. 
What can cause this issue?

Comment: How can anyone answer this when you don't post any code, schema, error messages? Most likely you have a corrupt file. Or the "Excel" file isn't, it's just a CSV file with a fake extension

Comment: A wild guess (since there's not enough relevant information to be sure of an answer): are there differences between locale information of the two Excel files? Version differences? Macro's in the original file that mix things up? Those might be non-existent when copying the data.

Please give us some more relevant information, for instance by making the Excel files available or diving into their specific differences.

Comment: I do not have any error while upload both of files. There is no macro and I have cleared all formatting and this did not help. Unfortunately I cannot give any code or files I just hoped that it is common issue

Comment: I have found solution for this problem. The problem was in encoding system. When I re save file in UTF-8 all works(File->Save As->Tools->WebOption and on Encoding tab you may change encoding). Perhaps it will help someone.